# How to send image from cloud function request to vision API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform

i've just setup a basic google cloud function with a http endpoint.
I would like to pass a image to this endpoint and send it all the way to the vision api(is already setup) and then send back the response from vision api to the response.

so basically:

```
 image in POST request -> cloud-function -> vision api ->|
response of vision api <- cloud function <- vision api <-|
```

This is the basic code for sending an image to the vision api:

```
const vision = require("@google-cloud/vision");

// Creates a client
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

const timeStart = new Date();
// Performs text detection on the local file
client
  .textDetection(file)
  .then(results => {
    const detections = results[0].textAnnotations;
    console.log("Text:");
    detections.forEach(text => console.log(text));
    const timeEnd = new Date();
    console.log(timeEnd - timeStart);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error("ERROR:", err);
  });
```

How do I handle the image in the POST request and send it to the vision API?

Thanks!

Comment: yes of course. but have not found anything good

Answer (score 0):

I would put the image in a Google cloud storage bucket, make the object [public](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart#storage%20browser) and only send the name/url of the bucket to the vision API.

Comment: This will make the image public available which is likely not desirable